# AngularJS - regular expression which should not start & end with space and should not consist double quotation (")

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have written ng-pattern for not to start and end with space.
And trying to match double quotation in $watch.

But it is not working. ng-pattern is also not working

my ng-pattern is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="wifiResult.ssid" 
     name="ssid"
     ng-class="{'inputError' : errorMsg}"
     ng-minlength="1"
     ng-maxlength="32"
     ng-pattern="/^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$/"
     required >
```

$watch in JS is:

```
$scope.$watch('wifiResult.ssid', function(scope){
        var regexToRestrict = /^["]+$/;

        if(scope){
            var pressChar       = scope.slice(-1);
            if(pressChar.match(regexToRestrict)){
                scope   = scope.slice(0,-1); // try to replace " to blank
            }
            else{
                console.log('not matched');
            }
        }       
        else{
            console.log('no scope');
        }
    });
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you clarify what you need to do? I understand why `"/^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$/"` does not work, but I can't get it what you are trying to do in the watch. That `^"$` matches an input equal to `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your regex to like this `ng-pattern='/^[^\\\\./:*?\"<>|][^\\\\/:*?\"<>|]{0,254}$/'` in your html to prevent user from entering (") in input and form can throw an error saying it's an invalid input.

In angular `ng-trim` is by default set to true so any white spaces surrounding user input are removed before assigning to `ng-model`.

You don't need a watcher unless and until you want the input value to be (") free every time user tries to enter some value in input field.It's an unnecessary operation to validate every time user changes something.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer ! It s working fine for me... :)